# php and oracle detele row

Tags: php, oracle

I am using this code for searching data from my table CUSTOMER but I am getting an error:
 in my keyword text felid   show this error----->>>>
   
**Notice**:  Undefined index: txtKeyword in **C:\xampp\htdocs\new_test\php_oracle_search.php** on line **10**

Code:

```
     <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
   <?php
 $txtKeyword = '';
  if(isset($_GET['txtKeyword']) && strlen(trim($_GET['txtKeyword'])) > 0) {
      $txtKeyword = trim($_GET['txtKeyword']);
 }
  ?>

    <form name="frmSearch" method="get" action="<?=$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];?>">
     <table width="599" border="1">
     <tr>
  <th>Keyword
<input name="txtKeyword" type="text" id="txtKeyword" value=" =$_GET["txtKeyword"];?>">
   <input type="submit" value="Search"></th>
      </tr>
       </table>
      </form>
    <?
if($_GET["txtKeyword"] != "")
     {

$objConnect = oci_connect("system","dm","XE");
$strSQL = "SELECT  * FROM CUSTOMER  WHERE (NAME LIKE '%".$_GET["txtKeyword"]."%' 
or EMAIL LIKE '%".$_GET["txtKeyword"]."%' )  ";
$objParse = oci_parse ($objConnect, $strSQL);
oci_execute ($objParse);
?>
<table width="600" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th width="91"> <div align="center">CustomerID </div></th>
    <th width="98"> <div align="center">Name </div></th>
    <th width="198"> <div align="center">Email </div></th>
    <th width="97"> <div align="center">CountryCode </div></th>
    <th width="59"> <div align="center">Budget </div></th>
    <th width="71"> <div align="center">Used </div></th>
  </tr>
<?
while($objResult = oci_fetch_array($objParse,OCI_BOTH))
{
?>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult["CUSTOMERID"];?></div></td>
    <td><?=$objResult["NAME"];?></td>
    <td><?=$objResult["EMAIL"];?></td>
    <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult["COUNTRYCODE"];?></div></td>
    <td align="right"><?=$objResult["BUDGET"];?></td>
    <td align="right"><?=$objResult["USED"];?></td>
  </tr>
<?
}
?>
</table>
<?
oci_close($objConnect);
         }
         ?>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: `isset` must subside that notice if there is no other probs

Comment: STRONG SUGGESTIONS: 1) Don't use repeated "$_GET[]" throughout your code.  Instead, fetch the input *once*, validate it, and use the known-valid variable instead.  2) Don't overload the same value "txtKeyword" for both "id" and "name".  IMHO...

Comment: how to use Serach button to Serach for multiple fileds like name , id, email...and etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code to validate `txtKeyword` before using it:

```
if(isset($_GET['txtKeyword']) && strlen(trim($_GET['txtKeyword'])) > 0) {
   //handle
}
```

For the notice error inside textbox, do below:

Put following code after opening `<body>` tag.

```
$txtKeyword = '';
if(isset($_GET['txtKeyword']) && strlen(trim($_GET['txtKeyword'])) > 0) {
   $txtKeyword = trim($_GET['txtKeyword']);
}
```

Then, wherever you want `$_GET['txtKeyword']`, use `$txtKeyword` instead.
Cannot explain much simpler than this.

Comment: thanks Rajesh sir now it working but in my keyword text filed this error show--->>>
<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: txtKeyword in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\new_test\php_oracle_search.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />

on line 10 : <input name="txtKeyword" type="text" id="txtKeyword" value="<?=$_GET["txtKeyword"];?>">

Comment: post the html so we can see. Its the same issue

Comment: this is full html code error on here---->>>
<input name="txtKeyword" type="text" id="txtKeyword" value="     <?=$_GET["txtKeyword"];?>">

Comment: you need to put the `IF` condition before the form

Comment: why do you want `$_GET["txtKeyword"]` inside textbox?

Comment: for searching data from database using keyword fields

Comment: edited the answer. Try that.

Comment: all table data print in o/p page ......and text fields problem same

Comment: can you edit the code so i can see

Comment: still incomplete. You are still using `$_GET["txtKeyword"]` inside the sql query, and your textbox code is incomplete

Comment: now see.... i am edit the code

Comment: edited your code...check

Comment: now in keyword text fields show only this  =$_GET[  
inside text...